# How to query the products in standard price book based on StandardPrice

Tags: pricebook

I am using the standard price book for the order ,but my standard price book contains same product with different standard price.How to query the products in standard price book based on the Standard price?

Comment: have you tried anything from your side already ? can you post a screenshot or sample data along with the query you tried ?

Answer (score 10):

The other answers will work with one caveat.  It will be difficult to unit test the code without using @SeeAllData=true.  If you want to be able to cover your code with a unit test that does not use @SeeAlLData=true, but instead uses the new [`Test.getStandardPricebookId()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_getStandardPricebookId), you will have to take a slightly different approach.

The below is an example unit test that inserts a PricebookEntry with the standard Pricebook Id. It is followed by three approaches to writing the application code, each better than the previous.

**Example unit test**

```
@isTest
static void testStandardPricebook() {

    Id productId = TestUtil.generateProduct().Id;

    PricebookEntry entry = new PricebookEntry(
        Product2Id = productId,
        Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
        UnitPrice = 10.0;
        IsActive = true
    );

    insert entry;

    // ... call the application code under test and then assert...
}
```

**Example application code (option 1 - fail)**

```
List<PricebookEntry> entries = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM PricebookEntry
    WHERE Pricebook2.IsStandard = true
];
```

The above fails to select anything because the Pricebook2 object itself is not visible. It was just the Id that was made available through the new [`Test.getStandardPricebookId()`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_getStandardPricebookId).

**Example application code (option 2 - ok)**

```
Id stdId = Test.isRunningTest() ?
               Test.getStandardPricebookId() :
               [SELECT Id From Pricebook2 
                WHERE IsStandard = true].Id;

List<PricebookEntry> entries = [
    SELECT ID
    FROM PricebookEntry
    WHERE Pricebook2Id = :stdId
];
```

Icky because you need Test.isRunningTest() in your application code, but works.

**Example application code (option 3 - cleaner)**

You could add a checkbox formula field to the PricebookEntry with a value of `{!Pricebook2.IsStandard}`. Your code would simplify to:

```
List<PricebookEntry> entries = [
    SELECT ID
    FROM PricebookEntry
    WHERE Is_Standard__c = true
];
```

The above works as the formula field value is evaluated correctly on the query.

---

I originally tinkered with this in this [blog post](http://peterknolle.com/salesforce-pricing-enhancements/) I wrote a few months ago.

Comment: So happy I stumbled upon your solution, scratched my head for 2 days!.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped!

Comment: I'm not sure adding a field just to accommodate tests is a lot cleaner it certainly makes the code cleaner but it mucks up the org so I dislike it just as much but there doesn't seem to be a better option. Pick your poison I guess.

Comment: Just FYI.  I am not sure if the option to use the formula field still works.  I have tried this today, and it works, but only if SeeAllData=true in my test.  Here is the query I was testing:

 [select id,  (select id, UnitPrice from  PricebookEntries where Is_Standard_Price__c = true  and IsActive = true) 
                                   from Product2 ]

Answer (score 0):

The standard prices are held in PricebookEntry, so you would want to build your query around that and use a filter on the Parent Pricebook Name, Product Name and Unit Price. Something like this:

```
Select PriceBook2.Name, Product2.Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice, Name From PricebookEntry WHERE  PriceBook2.Name = 'Standard Price Book' AND Product2.Name = 'Test Product' AND UnitPrice = 750.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add the same product multiple times to the standard price book. You might have the same product name (but internally they are different product2 records with different salesforce ids and possibly has different product codes)

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT Id,Name,Product2.Id,Product2.Name,UnitPrice 
FROM Pricebookentry 
WHERE PriceBook2.IsStandard=true 
AND Product2.Name='yourProductName' and UnitPrice=YourProductPrice
```

Please go thru this [reference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_pricebook2.htm) to understand how Product2, PriceBook2 and PriceBookEntry objects are related and how they link to Opportunity, Orders, etc..